# Why do I need to '@import compass' in all my sass files for precompilation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, compass-sass

I'm using Rails and Compass. Everything works great until I deploy to production at which point I hit:

```
bundle exec rake RAILS_ENV=staging RAILS_GROUPS=assets assets:precompile'
 ** rake aborted!
 ** Undefined mixin 'column'.
 ** (in /....../app/assets/stylesheets/clients.css.sass)
```

application.css.sass

```
@import compass
@import _blueprint
@import "compass/layout/sticky-footer"
@import "compass/css3/gradient"
@import "partials/_base"
@import "blueprint/reset"
@import "blueprint/colors"
@import "blueprint/grid"
@import "blueprint/fancy-type"
@import "blueprint/scaffolding"
@import "blueprint/form"
@import "clients"
```

clients.css.sass

```
#clients
  +column(4)
```

So you can see that clients.css.sass does not import compass, blueprint, etc, b/c it's imported by application.css.sass. But why is the asset compiler trying to compile this file on it's own? I can fix it by adding '@import compass' to each css.sass file but it doesn't seem like I should have to.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure your application manifest doesn't include `require_tree .` or similar. If sprockets is requiring the file outside of a sass import it will always raise this error. I had a lot of trouble with that at first.

If that's not the case, what version of Rails are you on? In the early Rails 3.1.x there were some issues with rake precompile that were fixed later...

Comment: I do not have require_tree anywhere. Using Rails 3.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I have found with Rails and the Asset Pipeline that you need to `@import` compass and blueprint sub elements using the partial notation. To get the `column` function to work you would need:

```
@import "blueprint/_grid"
```

As an aside, any reason why you aren't using quotes for the first two lines - I would have expected the following was required:

```
@import "compass"
@import "blueprint"
```

Although not 100% certain in this case if the `blueprint` line needs the leading `_` although I definitely import `compass` without it under Rails 3.2.3